# CUDA 7.0, invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'

Tags: c++11, cuda, clang

I've recently downloaded CUDA 7 and set it up to work with my project. On Mac, CUDA 7 requires clang to be the host compiler.

Now, I'm using a number of C++11 features. I've enabled these with -std=c++11 passed to nvcc this works. However, if I pass -Xcompiler -std=c++11 to nvcc, I get the following error regardless of if I also passed -std=c++11 by itself. The error is:

"invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'"

It seems like this should work, it certainly does with GCC. Anyone have a workaround. Otherwise, I'll file a bug report with Nvidia.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with 6.5/gcc either - I guess CUDA generates C code from what you've written. Why do you think you need `-Xcompiler` at all? Example at CUDA7 release notes says to use `--std=c++11`, that should be enough.

Comment: Interesting! It does work for me with 6.5 and GCC, not sure why it's different. The problem comes about because I specify -std=c++11 as a host flag, and FindCUDA.cmake automatically forwards it as -Xcompiler -std=c++11 to nvcc. (I need it as a host flag because for my host-only files.)

Comment: So if you specify just `-std=c++11` without `-Xcompiler` manually (without cmake or anything else, just `nvcc`), it compiles fine?

Comment: Yep! If I specify -std=c++11 separately to nvcc and the host compiler, things are perfect.

Comment: @user2333829 Wouldn't that indicate that the problem is with CMake constructing incorrect compiler invocations, rather than a problem with any component of the CUDA software stack?

Comment: Yeah, that could be considered the case. I've also talked to the author of FindCUDA.cmake about it.

Answer (score 2):

`nvcc -dryrun ...` will show what commands `nvcc` will execute. I don't currently have access to CUDA 7, only 6.5, but mine issues, among other things, two commands that compiles generated C source. This code generated by `cudafe` and have to be compiled by C compiler, but `-Xcompiler` adds options for both C and C++ modes.

I guess difference with my gcc situation is that I'm getting a warning while you have an error (this is exactly how gcc and clang differs in that case). For both compilers I don't see any way to suppress it, so I guess you have to fix your `.cmake` files to omit `-Xcompiler` options. This options shouldn't be used for language standard, just some very compiler-specific things.

Answer (score -3):

Of course it doesn't work. You are specifying C++ options while using a C or Objective-C compiler. The source files must be C++ or Objective-C++.

Comment: I don't think that's clear at all! CUDA is a C++ language. My source files are C++. The host code, also C++, is processed with the host compiler (in this case clang). It compiles fine when I don't specify the -Xcompiler -std=c++11 flag, and only specify the -std=c++11 flag.